# Break string naturally instead of using Can Grow

Tags: crystal-reports

I've got a string that sometimes is longer than the space on a table I have allocated. The issue I have is I cannot use the "can grow" feature to let it go to a second line as I have followup rows as detail sub-sections.

So what I'm thinking is if I can figure out how to naturally (ie on a space) break the line, similar to how "can grow" would break the line, via a formula, then I can create a formula that will match the second, third, etc. lines based on whether the follow up detail sub-sections are shown or suppressed.

ie:
Details A - has the initial row.
Details B - might have text, might be suppressed.
Details C - might have text, might be suppressed.
Details D - might have text, might be suppressed.

So I can create a formula so if Details B is not suppressed then the second line shows under Details B. With some fancy if statements (or other method?) I can have the followup lines show on Details B and/or C and/or D, depending on content, so the entire string can be displayed. I just haven't figured out how to break the initial string in a "natural" way like word wrap would.

[image: Overview of report layout]

DevLibSubType is the field that may be longer than the space and I want to be able to word wrap.
The subreports in Details B, C, and D are the subreports that may or may not have information that needs to be printed.

Comment: Why don't you suppress your whole detail sections depending on text and if section is suppressed, then line is also not visible.

Comment: I don't follow what you are suggesting. Those details sections have other content that needs to display regardless of what this specific text block has. If they are not suppressed and I use a text area that "can grow", then that other data, instead of visually displaying as a next row, there is a gap row in that column of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect with 4 Formulas, but you'll need to specify an appropriate number of characters for each line. (In theory you could calculate the length of each letter individually, but that's *way* overkill.) So instead assume that 100 characters per line is just right.

Your Details A formula might look like:

```
LEFT({yourString},100)
```

Details B might look like:

```
IF LEN({yourString}) > 100 THEN MID({yourString},101,100)
```

Details C would be like:

```
IF LEN({yourString}) > 200 THEN MID({yourString},201,100)
```

And so on. You can add additional clauses if you want to break the line based on spaces or punctuation by iterating through the characters backwards until you encounter one of these. Then push the resulting length into a shared variable for the next formula to use.

Comment: So, I tried this, my concern is that may interrupt the line mid-word. I was wondering how it's done in, say, a text editor, where the word wrap feature interrupts the line at the space character, and if that is something that can be easily implemented with the commands available in Crystal Reports.

thanks!

Comment: @tincanfury I address how to do that in the last paragraph, but just like before it's not what Crystal was made for. Honestly your best bet for something that can be "easily implemented" is to redesign your report to allow space for Can Grow.

Comment: right, but I don't know how to iterate backwards through the string, I'll have to do some more research into what command allows for this.

I tried to think of and implement a method that allows for "Can Grow" to work, but since Can Grow" pushes that section longer and each detail line may or may not appear I wasn't able to find a combination that worked without causing some sort of weird gap if any of the detail lines did not need to be printed.

thanks!

Comment: @tincanfury There isn't a pre-made command, you'll need to use loops and shared variables. Can you edit your post to include a preview of your report, minus any sensitive information? It sounds like your best course of action is a redesign, but we can't redesign what we can't see.

Comment: Have you tried putting DevLibSubType into its own section, going to the Section Expert, and turning on "Underlay Following Sections?"

Comment: yea, but Underlay Following Sections causes those sections to literally be laid under (ie underneath) the section you set that true for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159179/discussion-between-4444-and-tincanfury).